# Persist Grafana Dashboard on kube-prometheus and expose it

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

I've installed https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus and create the appropriate pv/pvc in order to persist default dashboard.

I've a set of specific dashboards, if I try to import them from GUI everything works fine, but if the pod restarts obviously I lose my custom dashboard.

Anyone has the same issue? any idea to solve it?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the dashboard inside configmap as mentioned below:

```
metadata:
   labels:
    grafana_dashboard: "1"
```

Also to persist dashboards to outlive pod deletion follow the below steps:

1. Create your custom dashboard through the UI.
2. Click on the “Save” button which will pop up a “Cannot save provisioned dashboard” window. There you can click on the “Save JSON to file” button.
3. Save the json file to your computer.
4. Using kubectl command-line tool which is configured to communicate with your k8s cluster, create a new ConfigMap using the following command: `kubectl create configmap my-custom-dashboard --from-file=path-to-file.json`
5. Add a label to the newly created ConfigMap: `kubectl label configmaps my-custom-dashboard grafana\_dashboard=1`

Above steps are derived from this Github [link](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/issues/1637#issuecomment-511860888).

Comment: Please let me know whether the shared info was helpful. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries. If the provided information was helpful,you can check this link. [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Just one question : configmap must be referentied somehow in grafana deployment?